Can I move my Boot Partition to the beginning of the drive?
I would like to move my boot partition to the beginning of my drive (The green one in the screenshot. That way I can join my allocated space and move that to the end of the drive? Any help is greatly appreciated.
Screenshot from Gparted

Rinzwind,   I've never heard of using a swapfile to boot from. I'd be interested if you have a link about it.

i miswrote sorry.

There is no extremely simple solution to move partition but yes.

Create a partition appropriate size(recommend previous size).
Format filesystem to FAT32. It is a principle to use PC.
Copy from previous files to the new.
Update configuration using bootctl.
Check /etc/fstab if boot partition declared as UUID.


PICO      I ended up just booting to a Live USB and moving the boot partition with Gparted Then just messed with the other partitions after a reboot and all went well. Thanks for your help.
